# Using several filters inside xPath not filtering correctly

Tags: xml, xpath

For each `<Reader>` node, I have the following status nodes: `<Status>`, `<WebChatStatus>` and `<WebCamStatus>`.

Each of these nodes has three available values: `Available`, `Busy` and `Logged Off`.

I'm trying to filter out an XML feed that returns only readers where `<WebChatStatus>` is `Available`, and either `<Status>` or `<WebCamStatus>` is not `Busy`.

So ultimately, I want to show readers who's Webchatstatus is available, but not if their Webcamstatus or Status is busy.

This is wha tI have, but this is just pulling in every reader regardless of status:

```
$webchatReaders = $xml->xpath('/ReaderDetails/Reader[WebChatStatus = "Available" and Status != "Busy" or WebCamStatus != "Busy"]');
```

Example of XML file:

```
<ReaderDetails>
    <Reader> // Should not be displayed
        <Status>Available</Status>
        <WebChatStatus>Logged Off</WebChatStatus>
        <WebCamStatus>Logged Off</WebCamStatus>
    </Reader>
    <Reader> // Should not be displayed
        <Status>Busy</Status>
        <WebChatStatus>Available</WebChatStatus>
        <WebCamStatus>Logged Off</WebCamStatus>
    </Reader>
    <Reader> // Should be displayed
        <Status>Logged Off</Status>
        <WebChatStatus>Available</WebChatStatus>
        <WebCamStatus>Logged Off</WebCamStatus>
    </Reader>
    <Reader> // Should not be displayed
        <Status>Busy</Status>
        <WebChatStatus>Busy</WebChatStatus>
        <WebCamStatus>Logged Off</WebCamStatus>
    </Reader>
</ReaderDetails>
```

Comment: Can you share appropriate XML sample for the same?

Comment: @Andersson Have updated my question to include sample XML.

Comment: So should the second node be fetched? It seem like it meet the requirements, but marked with `"Should not be displayed"` comment

Comment: No because 'Status' is 'Busy'

Comment: So both `<Status>` AND `<WebCamStatus>` should not be `busy`?

Answer (score 1):

Try below XPath to get required output:

```
/ReaderDetails/Reader[WebChatStatus = "Available" and Status != "Busy" and WebCamStatus != "Busy"]
```